# How to implement C++ Task Scheduler

Tags: c++, multithreading

**I Know the following code is not Task Scheduler Perhaps**
**However, trying to get your valuable comments in understanding the scheduler**

I am trying to understand & come up with a bare minimum code which can be called as TaskScheduler.
I have the following code but am not sure if it suffices as scheduling.
Could someone provide the comments & code skeleton reference or links?

Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

int factorial_loc(int val) {
    int res = 1;
    while(val>0) {
        res *= val;
        val--;
    }
    return res;
}

queue<packaged_task<int()>> q;
mutex mtx;
condition_variable cond;

void thread_1() {
    unique_lock<mutex> ul(mtx);
    cond.wait(ul, [](){
       return !q.empty();
    });
    auto f = std::move(q.front());
    q.pop();
    f();
}

void run_packaged_task()
{
    packaged_task<int(int)> t(factorial_loc);
    packaged_task<int()> t2(std::bind(factorial_loc, 4));

    future<int> f = t2.get_future();
    thread t1(thread_1);
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> ul(mtx);
        q.push(std::move(t2));
    }
    cond.notify_one();

    cout<<"\n Res: "<<f.get();
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.    I gather you did not write this code and do not understand it, so what exactly are you looking for?  Looks pretty straightforward.  A function adds tasks to a queue. A thread pops them off the queue and executes them.

Comment: Hello @Joe,
 I am not sure what makes you think that. The queue has packaged task & another thread is popping it to execute it. I am trying to see how can I make it as Scheduling. What does task scheduler should do.

Comment: You could model your own tasks with an expected time they should run at As a (std::chrono::steadyclock::timepoint!) and a packaged task as member. Then you need a priority queue which sorts tasks on execution time point. Your mainloop (on execution thread) should use condition variable wait that checks either on new item queued or a timeout that is exactly long enough until the next task should run. (the newly added task could be the new front task and you should recalculate wait time for condition variable wait).

Comment: You did not code a scheduler, but a simple task queue. A task queue executes one task after another. A scheduler is usually able to interrupt a task and let other tasks run in a fair amount of time. Is that what you want to achieve? You should more precicly specfiy what your question/problem actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the following code but am not sure if it suffices as scheduling.

Why not just do this?

```c++
void run_packaged_task()
{
    cout << "\n Res: " << factorial_loc(4);
}
```

Maybe you think that my version of `run_packaged_task()` is not a scheduler. Well, OK. I don't think so either. But, as far as the *caller* can tell, my version does exactly the same as what your version does;

- It computes the factorial of 4,
- It writes the result to `cout`,
- And then, only when that's done, it returns.

---

Your code contains some of the pieces of a scheduler; a thread, a queue, a data type that represents a task, but you don't use any of those pieces to do anything that looks like scheduling.

IMO, you need to think about what "scheduler" means. What do *you* expect a scheduler to do?

Should a scheduler execute each task as soon as possible? Or, if not, then when? How does the caller *say* when? How does the scheduler defer execution of the task until such time?

Should the caller have to wait until the task is completed? Should the caller have an *option* to wait?

I don't know exactly what you mean by "scheduler," but if my guess is correct, then it would have somewhat in common with a [*thread pool*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/173575/200736). Maybe you could get some traction if you start by searching for examples of how to implement a simplistic thread pool, and then think about how you could "improve" it to make a "scheduler."